# apache 2 not restarting

Tags: networking, server, apache2

Hi I am having trouble restarting Apache, I get the error

```
(99)Cannot assign requested address: make_sock: could not bind to address 58.108.248.95:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

when I run the command

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
```

this is what I get:

```
tcp   0  0 127.0.0.1:8080  0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      2320/python
```

if I clear the port using

```
sudo kill -9 2320
```

and then restart `apache2` I still get the same error

if anyone has any info it would be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: Make sure you run `netstat` again after killing it to make sure this is not a process that's respawning. Also find out what that process is: `ps aux | grep -w 2320`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed from a standard package, you should be able to use

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You might also try the older

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

As looking into your netstat output it seems like yout default port 80 is not listening . first try to open port 80 then try restarting apache service